# How to detect Chrome Inspect Element is running or not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is there any way to detect whether the Chrome Inspect Element window is running?

For example if the user clicks "Inspect Element" in Chrome, the window shows a `Hello World` alert.

Is that possible?

Comment: hmmm, you can deinfately monitor a "Right Click", although I doubt you can see what option they pick. So you could change the behavior of the right click action and maybe show your box then?

Comment: yes Abe I know that I can change the right click. but really i want to monitor if inspect element is running and doing anything. for example running a javascript function.

Comment: See [Find out whether Chrome console is open](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256983/64949) for a working solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.onresize = function(){
 if((window.outerHeight-window.innerHeight)>100)
   alert('hello');
}
```

In action: http://jsbin.com/ediquk/

Note that it seems like the resize event gets fired twice, so you should check whether you alerted the use already.

Comment: Works in firefox too, but you need to put the alert inside in timeout, because otherwise the layout freezes. See http://jsbin.com/ediquk/3

Comment: Is it correct that this only works when the window is docked?

Comment: Yes. Only when docked. I don't see how you can detect a undocked inspector.

Comment: But this also fires whenever the window is resized... which happens a lot more often than opening the inspector.

Comment: I suspect this would also be triggered by someone with multiple toolbars, or other extensions which modify the browser's UI.  The Chrome bookmark toolbar, for instance, counts against this calculation.

Comment: It fires when the window is "restored"

Comment: @UnLoCo that's why you check the inner and outer height.

Comment: I double clicked the chrome title bar and it alerted

Comment: I try, but the alert goes off every time I change the size of the window to a smaller height

Answer (score 33):

**UPDATE** This no longer works. The property `console.profiles` has been removed in Chrome 29.

The only solution that's left is checking the difference between `window.outerHeight` and `window.innerHeight` as suggested by @Gerben. There is a library [devtools-detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect) based on this method which adds `devtoolschange` to the `window` object.

Alternatively, there is an effort in progress to create a Chrome extension using a more robust detection method, see this [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/4Ge-51oHiZI/Awzhrzdf2R8J).

---

Here's how they check if DevTools are open in the first challenge of [Discover DevTools](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/chapters/1/challenges/1) interactive course:

```
function () {
    console.profile(); 
    console.profileEnd(); 
    if(console.clear) { console.clear() };
    return console.profiles.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Hah! You're welcome. ;)

Comment: Works on firefox for firebug.

Comment: This guy created a micro test framework and a [demo page](http://adamschwartz.co/chrome-inspector-detector/) based on the solutions suggested here. Also, you're awesome, Paul :)

Comment: You can make this technique slightly less obtrusive by using a collapsed console group to hide the messages that are generated by running the profiler. See https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-inspector-detector

Comment: This will cease to work soon in Chrome: https://codereview.chromium.org/15816002 (Sorry, y'all)

Comment: @PaulIrish There's gotta be another way to detect whether the DevTools are open! Can't you guys just expose a boolean?

Comment: @PaulIrish and the appropriate event :) Looks like such functionality can facilitate app debugging process (as meta as it may sound)

Comment: there is another way but it's a bit hacky :) http://nepjua.org/check-if-browser-console-is-open/

Comment: Many of us dock our dev tools to the right. This will not work for us.