# How to check if Chrome Dev Tools are opened?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I found in the tutorial on codeschool.com (discover-devtools: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/chapters/1/challenges/3) that there is possibility to check if Chrome Developer tools are open? How to check it's state/get event of (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) pressed?

Comment: See [Find out whether Chrome console is open](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256983/64949) for a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

google is your friend here

```
function isInspectOpen()
{
    console.profile(); 
    console.profileEnd(); 
    if (console.clear) console.clear();
    return console.profiles.length > 0;
}
```

from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

this function will return true is the user has the developer tools open

**edit**

in response to your comment

```
$('#header').click(alert(isInspectOpen()))
```

is not properly formatted jQUery , try:

```
$('#header').click(function(){
   alert(isInspectOpen());
});
```

Comment: hm, calling the `isInspectOpen()` works fine :) (i.e. it reterns `true`). But if I set `setTimeout('alert(isInspectOpen())', 10000)` and close the DevTools still after 10 seconds it alerts `true`. Any idea why so? How could I test the function another way?

Comment: don't use a timeout to test this  ,   try just testing with the tools open , then with it closed

Comment: any Idea, how to call the `alert(isInspectOpen())` (or another way of notification, e.g. change text of some `div`) with closed DevTools? `$('#header').click(alert(isInspectOpen()))` doesn't work for me neither

Comment: Please note that we removed dangerous console.profiles from Blink: https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=151136&view=revision so the trick won't work for Chromium anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You could try a logging framework like log4js or similar. 
http://log4js.berlios.de/links.html#other

Your code would have less dependency on a specific browser.

Comment: to log smth. I need to find out how this smth. work (shows its work in browser e.g. which event does it fire/which state does it change), and how to do it that was a question ;) of course log4js is a good thing to show the event is happened