# Execute JS code only in debug mode

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

Is it posible to execute part of a js file only when I have the developer tools opened?

I want something like

```
#if DEBUG
executeMethodOnlyInDebugger();
#endif
```

but for JavaScript.

Comment: Well, you could always set your own flags inside the code, and just switch the value when you need to debug.

Comment: this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765287/how-to-check-if-chrome-dev-tools-are-opened

Comment: That would be nice, but you'd never be able to rely on all browsers doing the same thing. Safer to just set the flag manually.

Comment: That duplicate is specific to Chrome (and is now outdated). I think the OP wants to know if there's some standardized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) natively in javascript.

Comment: I don't think conditional compilation is relevant here. If he wants code to run (or not) based on the state of the dev tools, that would be a runtime effort. He's basically looking for a standard boolean flag.

Comment: @squint the code posted is akin to c#'s preprocessor directives, which is a form of conditional compilation. That the condition is "Is the devtools open" is sort of irrelevant.

Comment: I guess it depends on context. He didn't explicitly relate it to anything specific but I get your point. I can't tell for sure if he wants it activated when the tools open or not.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.
But you can use [devtools-detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect) for that. See the following answer: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256983/1075630)

Answer (score 1):

Try this library: https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

It does some inspection of the `window` object and emits an event when it detects the console has opened. I would probably be wary of including this in production code but it could make for a useful debugging tool in your use case.

Comment: Maybe that worked once, but it certainly doesn't work now (on Chrome, or on Firefox with the built-in debugger). [This issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/issues) suggests it doesn't work for Firebug, either, at least not reliably.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works for me in Chrome 45 and Safari 9: http://sindresorhus.com/devtools-detect/

Edit: Just updated Chrome to 46 and it still works

Comment: Works for me in FF, although as expected doesnt detect an undocked devtools.

Comment: Either way, I agree with the other posters that the most robust method would be to set your own debug flag (you could even control it via the query string or a hash fragment or something for convenience)

Comment: It does work for me on Chrome, turns out, but **only** if devtools are docked (so, rather like the Firefox bug). Same with Firefox. And the end of the day: Not reliable, not to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a way to check for that in Chrome and Firefox.
The best bet is to have a debug flag in your code.

Although IE gives console as `undefined` when developer tool is not open.
So for IE you can just do:

```
if(console){
  //dev tools is open
} else{
  //dev tools not open
}
```

Also have a look here for more info on chrome: 
[Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

Answer (score 1):

**For ASP.NET**

In _Layout.cshtml (for MVC) or Master (for web forms), add the following:

```
<script>
    @if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
    @:var DEBUG = true;
    }
    else
    {
    @:var DEBUG = false;
    }
    alert('DEBUG: ' + DEBUG);
</script>
```

The beauty of this is that you can turn it on/off using a configuration value in Web.config to allow debugging in any environment:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```