# Find out if Developer Console is active in the current webbrower (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, development-environment

While developing a **logging tool** for websites, especially for javascript code I need to know if the **Developement Tools** (IE: Developer Tools, Chrome: F12, Firefox: Firebug etc.) are **open**.

Until know the only possibily I have found in my research was to get it in **IE10** by asking for

```
window.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE
```

Are there any **variables** or **functions** which can be called in Chrome, Firefox (and Opera) to get the status of the browsers Developent Tools.

I know there is the `console` `object` but this object does not tell me if the DevTools are open or closed.

Comment: This has been asked at least two other times.

Comment: For IE11 you need you use `('__BROWSERTOOLS_DOMEXPLORER_ADDED' in window)` e.g. see http://jsbin.com/IJOwuje/1 also beware that in IE9/IE10 `window.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE` remains set for a tab even once the debugger tools frame is closed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this other SO thread useful: [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

There is some good information about both Firefox and Chrome in there.