# How to detect if browser inspector window is open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to detect if browser's inspector window is open?

We tried to detect it by comparing the window.outerHeight and window.innerHeight, but this does not work when inspector window is not attached to browser (is floating).

```
window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight > 100
```

Thanks,
Khachatur

Comment: Can you not just detach the inspector from that window?

Comment: Why do you need to know? If it is to allow the console statement in IE8, just do `window.console && console.log("whatever")` each time

Comment: @Dogoku — The question is asking how to detect when that is the case.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: We send JS crash reports to our server for feature analyses. But we needn't do this if inspector is opened (a developer is working on this).

Comment: Have the developer add &debug=1 to the URL and test it where you send

Comment: *Anyone* can open the inspector, not just your developers. @mplungjan's suggestion is a much better solution to your problem.

Comment: sure, everyone can open inspector. But the product is in dev stage for now, and only our developers and our testers are working on it.

Comment: @Khachatur In reply to your comment to a deleted comment: Yes, you can detect whether the devtools is open using the [`chrome.devtools`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html) extension API, and notify the page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for a more clear way to do it but here is one hacky way i'm using currently:

Normally the time spent between two new Date() calls is less than 100ms. So if you put debugger between them, user will at least spend more than 100ms there and we'll know that they opened the console.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
function isConsoleOpen() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  debugger;
  var endTime = new Date();

  return endTime - startTime > 100;
}

$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if(isConsoleOpen()) {
        // do something
    }
  });
});
```