# Can a global variable be made available only in the JS console?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a global reference *only* be available from a JS
console, but not available to other JS running on a page?

For example, could I set a variable `m` to `10`, so that...

```
<script>
    console.log(m);
</script>
```

Is a `ReferenceError`, but from the console...

```
console.log(m);
```

Prints `10`?

---

Edit:

The responses so far only touch on the basics of scope in JavaScript, but if this is possible, it's going to be way more hacky than adding a variable to a scope that only the console can see (yes, I know this doesn't exist).  Here's an almost-working example of what I'm looking for:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    window,
    "m",
    {
        get : function window_m_getter() {
            if (CONSOLE_OPEN) {
                return 10;
            } else {
                throw new ReferenceError('m can only be used in a console');
            }
        },
    }
);
```

This example would work if it were possible to detect whether the console was currently open, which [it really isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open), but it's pretty close.

The answer to this question is almost certainly **no**, but it isn't entirely because of scope.

Comment: And what would be the use?

Comment: No, the only way to limit the visibility of variables (or any other value) in JS is through Clousure, funciton scopes.

Comment: it'd not be a global variable if not everything could access it

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Potentially making debugging references available only from the console, but not to 'application code'.  But mostly just curiosity.

Comment: you can often make those global variables available only when debugging through clever breakpoints and use of the console during debugging. I often will do `window.foo = ...` while investigating something, then later on look at `foo` when all is done

Comment: If you're trying to limit access to data in JS, you're gonna have a bad time. What kind of "debugging references" are you worried about leaking to the application? You aren't keeping sensitive data in an object on the client side, are you?

Comment: @Steve Let's say it's an easter egg.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The developer console operates in the global namespace. It's the same one every script uses, hence the name. There is no private, different namespace for the console.

The very `console` object you are accessing to `log()` is part of this namespace, and thus available to everyone.

At most, you can declare global variables for the console **after** you've loaded all of your scripts, at the very end of the `<body>`, making them unavailable until after everything runs. This, however, won't stop scripts from accessing them afterwards, from triggered events.