# Detect from inside of the JavaScript that the Chrome browsers Debugger has attached to my code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have a web application that consists mostly of JavaScript and I know the only browser thats ever going to open that web page is going to be Chrome.
Is there a way for my JavaScript to realize that the developer console of Chrome has been opened i.e. the Chrome JavaScript debugger has attached?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: @dhsto Thanks! That looks promising...