# How to stop from data post from browser console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xss

I have been thinking over this issue from past few months. Recently, I have started with complete JS Built front-end, where the forms are posted using `Ajax`.

I have a doubt, how to recognize on the server side, from where the data is coming from. Is it coming from actual `form` event or it is coming from `browser console`.?

What I have tried:

**Creating a two way handshake**: Before posting the `form`, the Application will contact the server, and the server will send a `token` inside the cookie, which will be sent back with the `form` post. But, even if we post by browser console, that `cookie` will go carrying the token. So, Failed.

**Binding Hidden Field**: But if someone, is posting the data from browser console, he would definitely look for the hidden fields as well. Basically, he'll replicate my `AJAX` to send the same request, in the same fashion. *FAILED*!!

I am not able to figure out this part. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not “recognize” that in any way. All your server will see, is that a request has been made – so make it deal with that request accordingly. “Where” such a request comes from should not matter at all to your application, as long as it satisfies all necessary requirements (f.e. a correctly authenticated user, that is allowed to make such a request). If you think it does, then you are doing things wrong from the very beginning already.

Comment: You may want to review [this Chrome question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open).

Comment: @CBroe: Suppose, my server has to accept all the special characters that are present in the data, then how will I validate for a script tag. at the server end.? If the user posts a `<script>` tag from the console, then it will be there always right.?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here … if this is about XSS, then what I said still stands: Your application has to be able to handle _any_ kind of data that it gets send, no matter where that data comes from – and if only that “handling” of data would mean to _reject_ further processing. You can in no way rely on _“my app will receive only certain kinds of data, because I programmed the client-side part that way”_ – the data that gets send to your app might not even come from a “browser”, but literally anything else that is able to make an HTTP request …

Answer (score 4):

**Rule #1 of programming for the Internet:** *Never trust anything from the client. EVER.*

**Rule #2 of programming for the Internet:** *Never trust anything from the client. EVER.*

**Rule #3 of programming for the Internet:** *You can not make the client trustworthy.*

I know the first rule is duplicated twice, but it is worth it.

There is simply no way to do what you intend to do.

A person who wishes to send data to your server, via an AJAX request or a POST request, can easily do any of the following:

- Modify the form using browser tools or a proxy and force-feed in whatever information he wants.
- Capture the entire transaction, through a tool like fiddler2, and change the values and re-send them.  No browser needed.
- Modify the code running from your site to send (or allow) whatever data he wishes to send.
- Use a tool like `Curl` to fake an browser and send whatever information he wishes to.

There is simply no way of knowing, on your server, where that information came from.

From a security point of view, you simply can not trust *anything* -- *ever*.

Validate the credentials, give the user a login token (usually a cookie) and then still be suspicious of everything the client sends you.  If there is something that shouldn't be changed or updated, make sure your back-end doesn't allow it to be changed or updated.

We have tons of code in our application that looks like this:

```
if (user.HasPermission("MayUpdateFirstName") {
   record.FirstName = FormData.FirstName
}
```

That way, if FirstName is passed in, and the user can't modify it, then it doesn't get modified.

Comment: Who doesn't have the ability to change their first name?

Comment: @JanDvorak Egads, don't get me started.  Our app has an insane level of permissions, with pretty much every field being wrapped up like that.  WE do business-to-business software, and some of our clients only *their* customers to edit personal data. Some of our clients require that any changes to personal/profile information be done *by* an employee.  Some of these are for legal reasons in various countries -- if someone has all their tax forms made out to a certain name, all paperwork must be issued to that name.