# How to make js console tracker

Tags: javascript, console

How to make this with js:
If console or Dev Tools is opened will perform function:

```
function(){
   alert('Console is open.');
};
```

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. The only indicator is using the `debugger;` statement which enables debugging capabilities only when the debugging tools are available, i.e. open. However, not even that is reliably the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Chrome you could use:

```
window.onresize = function()
{
    if ((window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) > 100)
        alert('Docked inspector was opened');
}
```

Also Sindre Sorhus created an applet which you could use to detect whenever dev tools is open or not (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256983/5252192).

I put some code here to tell what does it do. Head [Here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/blob/gh-pages/index.js) and import this in your page. then use the below code to detect when devtools opens or closed (it alerts on change of the state of the devtools).

```
window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', function (e) {
    var adsf = e.detail.open;
    if(adsf) {var qwer = "open.";}else{var qwer = "closed."}
    window.alert('dev tools is '+qwer);
});
```

Other possible solutions are [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)