# Can I conditionally load if browser switched to Dev Mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm debugging my code in Chrome with Dev Tools.

I wonder if I can have JS loaded only when DevTools active in Chrome, and ignored otherwise. So that I could ship my code with debugging logic in production, without affecting application performance, for general users.

Something like

```
<!-- if dev tools working load /debuf.js-->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out whether Chrome console is open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the devtools-detect library: https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

It can detect if the DevTools are active, but it is not 100% correct

> Doesn't work if DevTools is undocked and will show false positive if you toggle any kind of sidebar.