# How to stop page hyperlink redirection dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I want to open hyperlinks in a div and stop hyperlink navigation.
Ideally this should work for all links on the page "especially when debugger / console is open"

1. How to detect if the console is open on all browsers?
   window.console, window.console.firebug doe not seem to work with me.
2. I am setting the `innerHTML` property of my div right now which opens all the images etc in my div. I want only the text to be streamed. How do I do that? This is my code:

   ```
   function load_home(){
       document.getElementById("main").text='<object type="text/html" data="my link path" ></object>';
   }
   ```

Comment: Try using iframe to display a different site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: There are some hacks how to detect if console is opened, but I don't think you can find universal solution for all browsers. For chrome you can try approach from [this thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30638226/2508019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop links from directing you to another page (what I'm assuming you mean by "hyperlink redirection"), use JavaScript to stop them with an event listener and `preventDefault()`. Try adding this to your code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

And in that anonymous function in the event listener, you can add the code to load / redirect as wished.