# Detect Chrome Extension background page console opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just like the title says, I'm wondering whether it's possible to detect when I click on "Background Page" for my test plugin on the "chrome://extensions/" page.

Right now when I open the background page, the console is undocked.  I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open) and found ways to make it work inside each content script.  But is there a way to make the plugin detect it's own console opening?

This function from that post inside my `background.js` doesn't seem to detect anything.

```
chrome.tabs.query({url:'chrome-devtools://*/*'}, function(tabs){
  if (tabs.length > 0){
    console.log('opened');
  }
});
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you needing to detect this event?  As the developer, you know when you're clicking on the link.  For your users, "go to `chrome://extensions/`, turn on 'developer mode', and click 'background page'" is a horrible user interface.

Comment: @Teepeemm I suspect it's the inverse, basically prevent inspection by the user. I don't think the fact that a debugger is attached is detectable.

Comment: @Teepeemm Xan is correct, it is to prevent inspection by the user.  I think I found the solution, although it is probably terrible for performance.  In the post I linked, there is a solution by "zswang".  I inserted that code into the background page of my plugin and it detects the open console...but I can't imagine running an interval at 1sec constantly is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Devtools windows are not visible to `tabs`/`windows` APIs anymore.

This has changed since the answer from '14 was posted - therefore this method no longer applies.

Unfortunately, I can't find a link to the Chromium issue that implemented that.

Comment: I think I found a solution, mentioned in the comment under my question