# How to find browsers console is open or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

how to check browsers console is open or not in js. I tried

```
if(window.console){ console.log('test');}
```

but it will always work

Comment: you dont need this, just console log if you have to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out whether Chrome console is open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @8odoros  I already tried that . But its not working for me. Any other solutions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @gcampbell i just want to close the browser tab when console is open

Comment: @gcampbell my project requires user not opening console?

Comment: @SKB You can't rely on something like this. You just have to make sure you're not printing anything sensitive to console or writing it in your source code.

Comment: @gcampbell well the customer wants the user not able to run js through console when visiting the website. I currently disabled console.log and window.open

Comment: @SKB An engineer at Facebook [tried to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21693931/6303733). Chrome fixed the "bug" that let them disable the console. Your only option is to verify things server-side.

Comment: @SKB Also remember that there are many other ways for someone to execute custom JS code, such as `javascript:` URLs, Greasemonkey, and intercepting network requests.

Comment: @gcampbell Thank you