# how to block user ip if user tried to access website scouce code

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

is it possible to block IP address if any user tried to access your WordPress website source code?

and i found this Wordpress plugin which does some sort of a activity like that.

https://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-amazing-security-plugin-for-wordpress/4177158 this plugin Notify you when someone is mousing about your WordPress site (included with visitor details like IP, user agent, referrer and even username!)

Comment: How would you go about serving your website if your users weren't allowed to execute the code?

Comment: If a User is able to access the Wordpress source code, your server is misconfigured.

Comment: I mean - how would you hide it from the inspector and right clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.
The user send the ip automatic. So you can just filter it on the top of your Webpage.

```
<?php
if ($_session('REMOTE_ADDR') == 'the ip you want to block') {
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is impossible to write a script that guarantees your server will be informed when the visitor is trying to look at the client-side source code (that's what client-side entails), it should be possible to detect whether the internal developer toolbox/console is opened in most browsers.
[Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

Another method you should consider to make it harder to reverse-engineer or mess with your code is using automatic code obfuscation before you deploy your website.