# Dev Tools - How do you make a webpage blank once you open dev tools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security, firefox

Recently someone showed me this video of a webpage completely disappearing when they tried to open Dev Tools. I am wondering how would I go about reproducing this.

[image]
They also said it doesn't work on Firefox. So I was wondering if it possible to make a similar script that would work with Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the link, but it looks like thos only work if the Dev Tool is docked onto the page itself. And wont work if it is undocked. As you can see in the video the Dev Tool is fully undocked and the script is still working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)