# Is there a way to make chrome devtools undetectable?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I want to see how stuff works on a website, but each time I open Devtools (or refresh the page), I get an alert saying Devtools is open. It blocked me from using Devtools, so I want to disable this feature.

So, I searched how to "jam" google chrome Devtools and got these results:
[Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)
https://coderwall.com/p/iktwug/detect-if-chrome-devtools-are-open
https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

But I can't find any information about making Devtools *Undetectable* or disabling this code. Tried undocking Devtools, didn't work.

This is their code blocking me from using Devtools:
https://hastebin.com/oxopowiduy.php

What should I do to make Devtools Undetectable?

Comment: Hi, just setting window.alert = function() {};   "empty function", then at least the alert (and with it the modal) is gone. Would that be a silly idea? Regards, M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome 73+ it's possible to open devtools before the page can run any code to detect it:

1. open `chrome://inspect`
2. click "Pages"
3. click "pause" on an entry for the tab you want to debug

Now you can inspect the page, find out how exactly it detects devtools, and defuse it. Judging by the code in your question, you can run `window.uomg.create.onchange = null`, but if not, set breakpoints in the code and debug it to find out a working method.

Comment: Inspecting does work; however, I was not able to defuse the code. Guess I'll just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer:

[Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open)

The answer to your question is "No" - the sites are probably using jscript to detect the console is open and you will not be able to send back a false negative.