# This page detects chrome devtool perfectly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

[This page](https://jwdriveplayer.com/play/5edf2f80239cc82513fcabdd) detects that devtools is open,
and moves me to https://www.google.com/.

But I am not sure how it works.

How does it work?

Comment: That's one of the dumbest and most user hostile practices I've ever seen. Let's dive into the code.

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: @LuudJacobs I tried to delve into it using Event breakpoints, but they never fire and the page redirects immediately, weird.

Comment: They probably used one of the techniques described in the anwers of the other question

Comment: They did it specifically using the "_Another version (from comments)_" part of [zswang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638226/479156). It's obfuscated [in one of their JS files](https://jwdriveplayer.com/_next/static/chunks/f7605c40edc4208d1358469c1bc28b364e0f0ef7.3a321c58372e948409cf.js). Specifically this part: `i=new Image;i[r("0x3")]("id",(function(){!0,window[r("0x1")][r("0x0")]=r("0x4")})),setInterval((function(){!1,console[r("0x2")](i)}),1e3)})`