# How can I prevent Chrome Developer tools from being detected?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Came across something unexpected today. There is a certain website which plays a video. However, when chrome devtools is opened it does two unexpected things.

1. It somehow detects that the chrome devtools has been opened without the use of a "debugger" statement, and still detects that it has been opened even if the devtools is not docked (i.e. its opened as a separate window)
2. It clears the console log (which I can prevent) but the code source section of this is recorded as "(unknown)" in the console log instead of a source:line# format (i.e. javafile.js:30, vm11:22, etc.) so there is no clickable link to jump to the relevant code.

[image: Unknown code source]

I've done searches on how to achieve this functionality and haven't succeeded so I am not sure how it is being done. Similar questions have been solved by either dealing with the "debugger" statement (in this case its not used), or by undocking the devtools, neither of which have helped me. I also haven't found  what causes an unknown code source so tracking down the code doing this has been more difficult.

The website that I am experiencing this on is vexmovies.org, and a link to an example page which has this behavior can be found here: http://vexmovies.org/chicken-run

Comment: Not sure how you searched but the detection methods are listed in the top hit on google when searching for "stackoverflow detect devtools" [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7798748). You can open devtools in paused mode via `chrome://inspect` (then Pages, then click `pause`) so the site code won't run.

Comment: this is being done by movie websites to prevent individuals and/or staff at adblock from being able to develop blocks for the ads they embed. As they figure it, if you cannot debug the page, it will be far more difficult to make a block for it.  You will notice the behavior of ads being blocked, then ads not being blocked, then starting over again, each time getting longer. The blocking of tools is just one of the many ways websites are combatting ad-blockers, if at least a bit. The biggest offenders are the illegal movie distributers, so as usual they are making the rest of us have to suffer.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to this question , but I found an alternative way to use one of dev tools's features , network sniffer , without being detected by websites that actively detecting and blocking dev tools. Well theres an extension on Chrome Web Store literally named "Network Sniffer" . So I used that and I managed to sniff videos url out of a similar website to your example site. Im guessing this is what you want to do ;).