# How to stop JS debugger or page freeze during inspect element in browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, freeze, javascript-debugger

I am trying to open developer tools on websites like theflixer dot tv but as soon as I open dev tools, the website freezes and gets stuck on debugger and then the whole browser gets frozen. I know that they are trying to keep bots away from their content but I am curious to know how websites can detect when dev tools are open.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open) stackoverflow answer but I would like to know if there is a way to prevent such thing so I can look into the actions of the website!

Comment: Just click the arrow jumping over the dot

Comment: If you mean by stop debugger arrow, it doesn't work. The script freezes entire browser and I have to close it.

Comment: I clicked the "jump over" arrow 3 or 4 times and was through