# Is it possible to prevent JavaScript Worker html5 game manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, console, google-chrome-devtools

In working to make a HTML5 browser game, I can't help but consider the fact that a game like that can't be competitive or valued based on the ease of editing the code of the game through dev console.

For example like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQaTW3vCqC0

The user changes around values of variables and then resumes the scripts causing the game to be directly effected.

I'm thinking of possible ways to avoid such manipulations:

- Custom Browser (setup like Tor? custom routing used to detect unhampered browser with no console tools avialable)
- detection if dev tools are open [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open) , [How to detect Chrome Inspect Element is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527442/how-to-detect-chrome-inspect-element-is-running-or-not/15567735#15567735) (but this is only Chrome, what about IE, FF, SF, O?

Any insight or additional thoughts would be great.

Comment: people did that years ago on NES/SNES, they even sold "game genie" which was like a bookmarklet version of a devtools hack. you need to police and validate user input server-side. same with games as order forms.

Comment: JS uses reference-based security, so if the outside world cannot ref the private game state, only call methods to affect it, it cannot be altered in devtools. ex of an un-modifiable value: (function(a){return function(){return a}}(5));

Comment: @dandavis I think if you set a breakpoint on that function you can still modify the value of `a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What good ways are there to prevent cheating in JavaScript multiplayer games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250403/what-good-ways-are-there-to-prevent-cheating-in-javascript-multiplayer-games)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Qantas that link is very helpful, and definitely more along the lines of a solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Being that JavaScript is a client side language, you'll be hard pressed to provide total security from having it manipulated.